# Disconnecting serial cable crashes nodejs

Tags: node-serialport

I am using node 0.10.36 with node-serialport 1.7.4 on windows 7 64bit

If I run node with serial cable plugged, the code is running with a serial port listed.  If unplug the cable, the node is crashed.

Here is my code:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var sp = null;
serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
    ports.some(function (port) {
        sp = new serialport.SerialPort(port.comName, { 
            baudrate: 19200 });
        sp.on('open', function () {
               console.log('Opened ' + port.comName);
        });
        sp.on('error', function () {
            console.log('Errored!!!');
        });
        sp.on('close', function () {
            console.log('Closed!!!');
        });
        return true;
    });
});
```

The console output is:

Opened COM3

undefined:0
TypeError: undefined is not a function

I appreciate any input why error/close events are not triggered, and how to make the nodejs running if serial port is not found. Thanks!

Comment: When you say the serial is unplugged, is this a USB to serial cable, or an old-style serial cable?

Comment: It is a USB to serial cable

Comment: It looks like this is a reported and unfixed issue, unfortunately: https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/352 
You might be able to catch the exception with https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/388